# Creating Columns from ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, query-optimization

I want to know if there's a better way to create columns from the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. What I did is basically rewrite the same code again and change the condition. Let me demonstrate.

```
CREATE TABLE TBL(
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  DATE DATE
  );
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1003, '2022-05-03');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1002, '2022-01-02');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1003, '2022-02-05');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1001, '2022-01-02');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1003, '2022-01-02');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1003, '2022-04-04');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1001, '2022-01-01');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1001, '2022-01-03');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1001, '2022-10-04');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1003, '2022-01-01');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1003, '2022-12-06');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1002, '2022-03-01');
```

This should give us:

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1003 | 2022-05-03 |
| 1002 | 2022-01-02 |
| 1003 | 2022-02-05 |
| 1001 | 2022-01-02 |
| 1003 | 2022-01-02 |
| 1003 | 2022-04-04 |
| 1001 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1001 | 2022-01-03 |
| 1001 | 2022-10-04 |
| 1003 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1003 | 2022-12-06 |
| 1002 | 2022-03-01 |

Here's the code I used to create only 3 new columns, but what if I want to scale this even more? **Is there a way to do it without coding column by column?**

```
WITH
  DTA AS (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE) AS RN,
      *
    FROM TBL
    )
SELECT DISTINCT
  T.ID,
  T1.DATE AS DATE1,
  T2.DATE AS DATE2,
  T3.DATE AS DATE3
FROM TBL T
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM DTA WHERE RN = 1) T1
ON T1.ID = T.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM DTA WHERE RN = 2) T2
ON T2.ID = T.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM DTA WHERE RN = 3) T3
ON T3.ID = T.ID
```

My code's output:

| ID | DATE1 | DATE2 | DATE3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 |
| 1002 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-02-05 |
| 1003 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-03-01 | NULL |

Comment: Snowflake doesn't have a built-in method for pivoting dynamically. I suggest you type  "Dynamic Pivot Snowflake" in search and look at some other workarounds using stored procedures

Comment: https://medium.com/snowflake/dynamic-pivots-in-sql-with-snowflake-c763933987c has one approach to Dynamic Pivot in Snowflake

Comment: @PhilCoulson -- why do you assume there is a need for dynamic?

Comment: https://medium.com/@adrian.white/pivot-multiple-values-in-sql-with-snowflake-5d570636a352

Answer (score 0):

You do need to code column by column but don't use the sub-queries -- like this

```
WITH
  DTA AS (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE) AS RN,
      [DATE]
    FROM TBL
    )
SELECT DISTINCT
  T.ID,
  T1.DATE AS DATE1,
  T2.DATE AS DATE2,
  T3.DATE AS DATE3
FROM DTA 
LEFT JOIN DTA AS T1 ON T1.RN = 1 AND T1.ID = T.ID
LEFT JOIN DTA AS T2 ON T2.RN = 2 AND T2.ID = T.ID
LEFT JOIN DTA AS T3 ON T3.RN = 3 AND T3.ID = T.ID
```

Note - technically you don't need a LEFT JOIN on T1 because there will always be at least one value.